# iPad: How can I determine if a UIView subclass supports fonts?

Tags: ipad, uiview, fonts

I need to traverse a viewcontroller's view hierarchy what font is being used.  Is there a generic way to determine if the view (and subclass of view) supports fonts?  I do not want to do a huge if-then-else:

```
if ([[view isKindOfClass: [UILabel class]) {
  // Do stuff
} else if ([[view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]) {
  // Do stuff
} etc. ...
```

due to the maintenance issue.  I prefer to have a method such as

```
if ([view canPerform: @selector(getFont:)]) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

but this does not work as one might hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the respondsToSelector method, inherited from NSObject.

```
if( [ view respondsToSelector: @selector( font ) ] ) {}
```

Or

```
if( [ view respondsToSelector: @selector( setFont: ) ] ) {}
```